# how to stop pyplot from popping up figures

Tags: python, memory, matplotlib, pdfpages

I write a number of plots to a pdf with a loop like the following. It works but there are two very annoying issues,

1) When the loop runs, i see a lot of windows ('Figure 1') popped up. I think the command `plt.close(fig)` does not work as intended. This' really annoying because I might be doing something else when it runs and those pop-ups block my view to the other tasks.

2) Probably related to 1), memory usage goes up dramatically. In my real script, plotting something like 50 pages of graphs eats up > 32 Gb of ram. How could that be?!

```
with PdfPages('Manyplots.pdf') as pdf:
  for j in xrange(100):
    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5,5))
    for fr in xrange(9):
      pp = fig.add_subplot(3,3,fr+1)
      pp.imshow(x, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close(fig)
```

My questions are

1) any way to close a figure after the plot is done?

2) better still, how to suppress blank Figure pop-up since it should really be writing to an external file in the background,

3) any better way to save a series of plots to multiple pages of PDF?

Comment: For 1 and 2, can you just remove the imshow call?

Comment: not sure what you mean? pls elaborate.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? And what OS?  I cannot reproduce this using matplotlib 1.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04, matplotlib 1.4.2, python 2.7.6

Comment: Are you running this through a script or interactively?  In your matplotlibrc file, do you see `interactive  :  True` (towards the top, below backend)?

Comment: i tried both, one in a script which i run from command line, and then i copied  over to run in spyder.

Comment: in my /etc/matplotlibrc, 'interactive' is commented out.

Comment: i just set 'interactive:False' and same pop-ups.

Comment: @wflynny: is my issue really related to version 1.4.2? Can you confirm that you really don't see this problme in 1.5?

Comment: @horaceT I don't see it in 1.5, but I can't confirm that upgrading to 1.5 will solve your problem.  There are a lot of variables here.  That said, I've used `PdfPages` often in the last few years and never remember seeing this bug.  Do you have local matplotlibrc file (~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc)?  It may also help to see the entire script you're running just to check there isn't a `plt.ion()` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of the problem. My main script includes an `import` of someone's utility script, which imports pyplot and has an extra line,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
```

When `plt.ion` is commented out, the popups are gone.